# Adding an Element Screener to ArrayList java

Tags: java

I've been looking for errors in my code, but at this point I am totally lost.  I'm trying to add an interface that I can use with lambda expressions to filter elements out of an ArrayList.  Before you tell me there's already a simpler way to do this, I want to code this myself.  The problem I'm having is that when I try to use an instance of something that implements this interface in my class to test each element, I get a bunch of errors.  These are the errors:

- Syntax error on token "if", new expected
- elementScreener cannot be resolved to a type
- screened cannot be resolved to a type
- Syntax error on token "}", delete this token

The following is my code for `DataSetGeneric` class:

```java
public class DataSetGeneric<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
    
    public ArrayList<E> getList(){
        return this;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<E> getList(Screener<E> elementScreener){
        DataSetGeneric<E> screened = new DataSetGeneric<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {
            E elem = get(i);
            if elementScreener.test(elem){
                screened.add(elem);
            }
        }
        return screened;
    }
}
```

The following is my code for `Screener` interface

```java
public interface Screener<E> {
    public boolean test(E obj);
}
```

Comment: I think you’re missing a bracket after the ‘if’ keyword

Comment: I see that you want to create the objects from scratch, but `java.util.function` package provides a functional interface `Predicate<T>` for your use case like Screener.

Comment: I think dave is right.  Change the line `if elementScreener.test(elem){` to `if (elementScreener.test(elem)){`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand where variable `obj` comes from in this line of code (from your question).

```java
screened.add(obj);
```

[Refer to method `getList(Screener<E>)` in class `DataSetGeneric<E>`]

In any case, the compiler error I get when I copied your code into my IDE (which is Eclipse 2021-06) was

> obj cannot be resolved to a variable

Also there is no `return` statement in method `getList(Screener<E>)` and that gives me the following compiler error.

> This method must return a result of type ArrayList<E>

In other words, I did not get any of the compiler errors you claim to be getting.

Simply replacing `obj` with `get(i)` and adding a `return` statement fixes the compiler errors.

Here is working code, including a `main` method for testing the code.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataSetGeneric<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    public ArrayList<E> getList(){
        return this;
    }

    public ArrayList<E> getList(Screener<E> elementScreener) {
        DataSetGeneric<E> screened = new DataSetGeneric<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
            E elem = get(i);
            if (elementScreener.test(elem)) {
                screened.add(get(i));
            }
        }
        return screened;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataSetGeneric<String> dsg = new DataSetGeneric<>();
        dsg.add("alfa");
        dsg.add("bravo");
        dsg.add("charlie");
        dsg.add("delta");
        dsg.add("echo");
        dsg.add("foxtrot");
        dsg.add("golf");
        dsg.add("hotel");
        dsg.add("india");
        System.out.println(dsg.getList());
        ArrayList<String> screened = dsg.getList(e -> e.contains("l"));
        System.out.println(screened);
    }
}

interface Screener<E> {
    public boolean test(E obj);
}
```

Here is the output when I run the above code.

```
[alfa, bravo, charlie, delta, echo, foxtrot, golf, hotel, india]
[alfa, charlie, delta, golf, hotel]
```

### EDIT

I just noticed another error in the code in your question (even after you edited your question and replaced the original code with the code from my answer). Refer to this line:

```java
if elementScreener.test(elem){
```

That line is missing parentheses that enclose the condition. The line should be:

```java
if (elementScreener.test(elem)){
```

The missing parentheses causes the compiler errors that you claim to be getting.

Comment: I cannot believe I submitted this code without editing the changes I made before I submitted it after checking the code.  Please check the code again.  I'm still getting an error.